# Is PdfStamper disposing output stream? (iTextSharp)

Tags: c#, itext, code-analysis, idisposable

I am using iTextSharp to add page numbers to a PDF with C#. While running code analysis the `MemoryStream` for the output is suspected to be disposed more than once. [See this warning generated by Visual Studio.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CA2202);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true) Is this an API problem? Should the second parameter of `PdfStamper` be marked as `out`? Is there a way for me to fix this warning?

```
MemoryStream mem = null;
PdfReader reader = null;
PdfStamper stamper = null;
try
{
    mem = new MemoryStream();
    reader = new PdfReader(m_pdf);                
    stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, mem);

    // do stuff
    stamper.Close();
    var result = mem.ToArray();
}
finally
{
    if(stamper != null)
    {
        stamper.Dispose();
    }

    if (reader != null)
    {
        reader.Dispose();
    }

    if (mem != null)
    {
        mem.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am the developer of iText (other people ported it to C#) and based on my knowledge of iText, I am worried when I see your code. I don't know the `Dispose()` method in `PdfStamper`, but I know that you always need `stamper.Close()`. The `Close()` method also closes the underlying output stream. It would be very wrong to close the output stream *before* closing the `stamper` as this would lead to amputated (incorrect) PDF files.

Comment: I have the same problem with disposing of the `reader` before disposing of the `stamper`. If the `stamper` needs a resource from the `reader` in order to finalize the PDF creation process, an error will be thrown because it will no longer have access to the closed `reader`. I prefer defensive programming, so I would switch both so that the `stamper` is disposed of before disposing of the `reader`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie You are right, the `Close()` was missing. I edited the code especially the order of disposing the objects. I guess this prevents any possible problems double disposing.

Comment: You can write that much more with `using` directives.

Comment: I meant *much tighter* and also more secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really an answer but to expand upon what @mkl said, switch over to `using` directives since those perform the `try/finally` stuff for you automatically.

Below is the way I (and probably everyone else that uses iTextSharp) would generally recommend to interact with iTextSharp. The outer `using` is BCL stuff, in this case the `MemoryStream` and the inner `using` statements are iTextSharp stuff.

```
//Will hold our raw PDF bytes
Byte[] result;

//BCL stuff first
using (var mem = new MemoryStream()) {

    //iText stuff in the middle
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(m_pdf)) {
        using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, mem)) {
            // do stuff

        }
    }

    //iText is completely done and disposed of at this point
    //so we can now grab the raw bytes that represent a PDF
    result = mem.ToArray();
}
```

As an aside, not necessarily for the OP but just in case someone else sees this, there is almost never (and by "almost never" I really mean "never") a good reason to *not* close the underlying stream. You can read from the stream by grabbing the raw bytes and writing to it again never makes sense.

Comment: Well, I don't know about C#, but in Java, there could be reasons not to close the stream. For instance: you are writing more than one file to a ZipOutputStream. Or your stream is a mail message and you need to write PDF bytes to that stream to add a PDF attachment. I knew more examples, but I forgot them ;-)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, I tossed the "almost" in there because there are a few edge cases but unless someone knows about these I wouldn't recommend them. Complex things like zip files and email messages are generally abstracted to objects that have "add" methods that take files, bytes or previously created streams. Internally the object probably has a stream but that stream is rarely exposed. There's some overhead, true, but it makes debugging so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The following allowed me to keep the MemoryStream open after the stamper is closed:

```
pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
```